# regex capture repeated phrases

Tags: regex, r

I can capture repeated words pretty easily using: 
`"(?i)\\b(\\w+)(((\\.{3}\\s*|,\\s+)*|\\s+)\\1)+\\b"` but this regex does not seem to extend to mutipe words (and why should it in its current state).  How could I find repeated phrases using regex?

Here I extract repeated terms (regardless of case) but the same regex doesn't word to extract a repeated phrase:

```
library(qdapRegex)
rm_default("this is a big Big deal", pattern = "(?i)\\b(\\w+)(((\\.{3}\\s*|,\\s+)*|\\s+)\\1)+\\b", extract=TRUE)
rm_default("this is a big is a Big deal", pattern = "(?i)\\b(\\w+)(((\\.{3}\\s*|,\\s+)*|\\s+)\\1)+\\b", extract=TRUE)
```

I would hope for a regex that would return:

```
"is a big is a Big"
```

for:

```
x <- "this is a big is a Big deal"
```

To cover corner cases here's a larger desired test and output...

```
    "this is a big is a Big deal",
    "I want want to see",
    "I want, want to see",
    "I want...want to see see how",
    "this is a big is a Big deal for those of, those of you who are.",
    "I like it. It is cool",
)


[[1]]
[1] "is a big is a Big"

[[2]]
[1] "want want"

[[3]]
[1] "want, want"

[[4]]
[1] "want...want" "see see"    

[[5]]
[1] "is a big is a Big" "those of, those of"

[[6]]
[1] NA
```

My current regex only gets me to:

```
rm_default(y, pattern = "(?i)\\b(\\w+)(((\\.{3}\\s*|,\\s+)*|\\s+)\\1)+\\b", extract=TRUE)

## [[1]]
## [1] NA
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "want want"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "want, want"
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] "want...want" "see see"    
## 
## [[5]]
## [1] NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does what you want (note we only allow a single space, `...`, or `,` as separators, but you should be able to tweak that easily):

```
pattern <- "(?i)\\b(\\w.*)((?:\\s|\\.{3}|,)+\\1)+\\b"
rm_default(x, pattern = pattern, extract=TRUE)
```

Produces:

```
[[1]]
[1] "is a big is a Big"

[[2]]
[1] "want want"

[[3]]
[1] "want, want"

[[4]]
[1] "want...want" "see see"    

[[5]]
[1] "is a big is a Big"  "those of, those of"
```

Comment: Nice.  So simple in comparison to my stuff.  Let's give this a bit for people to poke holes at and for alternate answers.  Thank you +1  PS I always get scared to use `.*` as if though it will eat the world.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
> regmatches(x, gregexpr("(?i)\\b(\\S.*\\S)[ ,.]*\\b(\\1)", x, perl = TRUE))
[[1]]
[1] "is a big is a Big"

[[2]]
[1] "want want"

[[3]]
[1] "want, want"

[[4]]
[1] "want...want" "see see"    

[[5]]
[1] "is a big is a Big"  "those of, those of"
```

Here is a visualization (except there is an error in the visualization - the `\S` parts should be within the group.

```
(?i)\b(\S.*\S)[ ,.]*\b(\1)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/9Y6EQhc8IIzD1WkY)

You might want to replace `[ ,.]` with `[ [:punct:]]`.   I did not do that since debuggex does not support POSIX character groups.

Comment: Simpler +1 but fails on something like `"I like it. It is cool"`.  I added this to the corner case.  I'd expect this to return `NA` or `""` as a pause is usually indicated by `...` or `,` whereas endmarks denote the end of a sentence which is not repetition.  My apologies for not mentioning this in the original post.

Comment: Looks like this is more or less equivalent to the one I put up, except it uses a character range instead of `(?:|||)` for the alternate allowable delimiters, unless I'm missing something.  Also, not a big deal, but do you want the `+` to allow more than one repetition of `\\1`?